# Why does my label.new function only go back a couple months?

Tags: pine-script

I'm just learning about the label.new function in the documentation. When I apply the sample code to a chart, it only goes back about 2.5 months:

```
//@version=4
study("Bar Labels", overlay=true)

label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none,
      text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high))
```

I have tried to override this with some conditions:

```
bi = bar_index < 7572?1:0
label.new(bi, na, style=label.style_none,
          text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high), yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

In which case nothing prints on the chart if bar_index is below that date 2.5 months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second snippet won't work because it's trying to print a label at *bar_index==1* from bar 0, which is in the future at that time. Labels and lines can only be plotted in the future when using `xlox=xloc.bar_time`. This will work:

```
//@version=4
study("")
if bar_index < 7572
    label.new(bar_index, na, style=label.style_none,
      text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high), yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

A garbage collector deletes old labels and leaves only the last ~50; that's the reason why you are only seeing a few of those you printed. You will find useful information in the Pine User Manual:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#total-number-of-drawings

---

Example code to show how different types can be cast to bool type. You can use all these `cond*` vars in the `if` test because Pine will auto-cast them to bool or because they are already of bool type. You may not, however, use all of them as arguments to the `x=` parameter in the `label.new()` function because it expects an int:

```
//@version=4
study("")
cond1Bool   = bar_index < 7572
cond2Int    = bar_index < 7572 ? 1 : 0
cond3Float  = bar_index < 7572 ? 100.99 : 0
cond4Bool   = bar_index < 7572 ? true : false
cond5Na     = bar_index < 7572 ? na : na
if cond1Bool
    label.new(bar_index, na, style=label.style_none,
      text="x=" + tostring(bar_index) + "\ny=" + tostring(high), yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually don't see where I'm trying to print a label at bar_index==1 from bar 0. Can you point out where in my code I've done that? If so, it's inadvertent on my part.

Comment: In your second snippet you have the ternary expression `bar_index < 7572?1:0`. When your script first runs on bar 0, that expression will evaluate to 1, and so the following `label.new()` line will try to create a label at bar_index `bi` (which will equal 1) from bar 0.

Comment: I thought that using a 1 and 0 in the ternary conditional operator would return a true or false. I've used it that way in the past. However, in this case the 1 and 0 represent those actual bars in the series. Any clarification on the boolean use of this structure vs. what happened here would be great. Also a little confusion about counting bars: When counting bars in bar_index, is the first bar 0 or 1? And why in other contexts do the bar numbers go the opposite direction, from 0 at the current bar, upwards as they go back?

Comment: If you look at Pine's [auto type-casting rules](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Type_system.html#type-casting) you'll see that they are very generous in casting to boolean. Any float or int can be used as a boolean where 0 will be considered false, na will be considered neither true nor false (more on the na special case in booleans [here](http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#why-do-some-logical-expressions-not-evaluate-as-expected-when-na-values-are-involved), and any other numeric value different than zero will be considered true. Added code to show examples.

Comment: As for bar_index values, they start at 0 at the first bar and increase going right until the last bar in the dataset. This is not to be confused, however, with the [history-referencing](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) index used to refer to past elements in a series, where that index goes from 0 for the current bar, to 1 for the previous bar, etc., back to bar_index to refer to the first bar in the dataset. The first example number increases left to right; the second one right to left.